# get HTML element style with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I am trying to retrieve backgroundColor of an HTML Element. But when I check the style with js, everything is either empty or undefined. But when I check this element on developer console it I can see there is a backgroundColor. I could not understand what's wrong. Do you have any tips what can cause this problem?

```
document.getElementById("id1").style
```

[image: JS get style result]

[image: Developer console]

Comment: `getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("id1")).getPropertyValue('background-color')`

Comment: element `style` property only contains inline styles. `getComputedStyle` function gives you all the styles that are applied to the current element.

Comment: Ok, I could get the style with JS. Actually I am trying to write unit test with react enzyme. How could I get the calculated style with react/enzyme. Following code does not work since style value is undefined! expect(wrapper.find('div.profile-card').props().backgroundColor).toBe('red');

Comment: By the way, could you see the attached images? I think imgur is not reachable from my country and I could not see the images? I am curious that is it visible to others? I would appreciate if you let me know!

Comment: @wasabi yes it is visible. please edit your question and be more specific if the answers below do not address the issue

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973, thanks for the response. The answer addresses the issue, i will accept the solution. I think, Solving the problem for react should be a separate question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `window.getComputedStyle`

read more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

basically `style` property only read the inline style on the element

Answer (score 1):

You should try fetching the applied styles using the window.getComputedStyle method.

```
let element = document.getElementById("id1");
window.getComputedStyle(element);
```

Comment: I try this code but it did not work on chrome javascript console! Can you confirm that there is no syntax error at the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("id1"));
```